# Callback function isn't waiting until the first function is complete. How do I fix/work around this?

Tags: jquery, callback, show-hide

I have a "slideshow"...of sorts. I'm trying have a div fade out, followed by another div fading in.

The problem is, the visible div doesn't disappear completely before the new div appears. This causes an awkward flash where both divs are present at the same time.

NOTE: I cannot stack the divs using absolute positioning, because I want the wrapper (parent) div to expand with the contents. I can't seem to achieve this when I take the divs out of the "flow" by absolute positioning them.

JSfiddle: [HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/a7mCL/1/)

Here is the html:

```
<a href="#" class="red">RED</a> 
<a href="#" class="blue">BLUE</a> 
<a href="#" class="green">GREEN</a> 
<a href="#" class="yellow">YELLOW</a>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
```

...the CSS...

```
#red, #blue, #green, #yellow{display:none; width:200px; height:200px;}
#red{background:red;}
#blue{background:blue;}
#green{background:green;}
#yellow{background:yellow;}
```

...and the JQuery.

```
$('a.red').click(function() {
  $("#blue, #green, #yellow").hide('fade', function() {
      $("#red").show('fade');
  });
});

$('a.blue').click(function() {
  $("#red, #green, #yellow").hide('fade', function() {
      $("#blue").show('fade');
  });
});

$('a.green').click(function() {
  $("#red, #blue, #yellow").hide('fade', function() {
      $("#green").show('fade');
  });
});

$('a.yellow').click(function() {
  $("#red, #blue, #green").hide('fade', function() {
      $("#yellow").show('fade');
  });
});
```

I've been fiddling with this forever! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/a7mCL/63/. One should always try to write concise code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.hide()` is running for all matched elements and then running the callback even when the matched element was not visible. By using the `.filter()` method you can ensure that the `.hide()' method, and thus the callback, only get fired once. This means that the code gets bulked out as you need to catch the case when nothing is shown already, but it does work quite well.

An example of this is

```
$('a.red').click(function () {
    var elements = $("#blue, #green, #yellow").filter(":visible");
    if (elements[0]) {
        elements.fadeOut(function () {
            $("#red").fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $("#red").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

And you can see this fully working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeteUh/a7mCL/62/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that the 'hide' animation takes zero time for elements that are already invisible. The complete callback in turn is fired *for each element in the sequence*, not only once when the animation ends. So the animation will complete instantly for any invisible element and fire the complete callback instantly.
To solve this, I tweaked the jQuery selector for the elements so that only elements that are actually visible get animated:

```
   $('a.red').click(function () {
       toggleVisibility("#blue, #green, #yellow", "#red");
   });

   function toggleVisibility(elementsToHide, elementsToShow) {
       var elements = $(elementsToHide).filter(':visible');
       if (elements.length) {
           // Hide visible elements first if there are any
           elements.fadeOut(function () {
               $(elementsToShow).fadeIn();
           });
       } else {
           // ...otherwise just show specified element directly
           $(elementsToShow).fadeIn();
       }
   }
```

So now the callback only fires once.

Cheers, Alex

EDIT: Didn't work if all elements were initially invisible; I changed the code accordingly. Also, the new snippet is more DRYish.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution, but there's one issue. Since all divs are hidden at first, the callback ends up not firing at all. Any tips on a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

use `.stop()` that will stop animating on DOM.

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

<kbd>[**`STOP`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use to delay the new div appearing by a short period of time, allowing the other animation to first finish.

```
.delay()
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

for example:

```
$('a.red').click(function () {
   $("#blue, #green, #yellow").hide('fade', function () {

       $("#red").delay(500).show('fade');
   });
});
```

Made a quick example, works nicely most of the time but every so often they will both be displayed at the same time for a moment. Just needs to be tweaked :) http://jsfiddle.net/a7mCL/15/

Comment: The worst possible thing you can do in a script is put delay. You can never be sure that it will work. Set relatively small delay and it may not be enough. Set a longer delay and you might be delaying more than required at most of the time. I would rather kill myself than use a delay().

Comment: I see, well thank you for teaching me something new. Will remember this in the future :)